# How to specify formControlName in template when formGroup is nested?

Tags: angular

I have an existing formgroup to which another formgroup is added. How to attach the formControls of second group inside the form tag?

This is how my form inside looks like.
Typescript file:

```
function one() {
    this.address = new FormGroup({
       country1: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
       pincode1: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
    })
}

function two() {
 this.address.addControl('secondaryAddress', new FormGroup({
       country2: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
       pincode2: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
    })
}
```

In template:

```
<form [formGroup]="address" (ngSubmit)='onAddressSubmit()'>
   <div class="col-sm-6 mb-5">
       <label/>
       <input type="text" formControlName="country1" class="form-control">
   </div>
</form>
```

Inside the form tag now I have to embed the secondary address formGroup. How to add conutry2 and pincode2?

Comment: you need enclosed the formControls of the nested FormGroup using `[formGroupName]` see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-nested-form-groups)

Comment: Thank You @Eliseo. I used formGroupName nut due to silly mistake it didnt worked. Issue solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `[formControl]` as below.

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="address.get('secondaryAddress')?.get('country2')" class="form-control">
<input type="text" [formControl]="address.get('secondaryAddress')?.get('pincode2')" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Adding [formGroupName] on input tag's parent div element worked for me. Thanks for sharing your answer.